# Load Common Lisp Module Programmatically

Tags: common-lisp

I just started learning Common Lisp a few weeks ago, so sorry if this is an obvious question. How can I load modules programmatically? I have a directory of "tasks", each a Lisp program, and would like to import each and run a specific function that they all contain.

I found out a way to iterate over a directory (via `UIOP:DIRECTORY-FILES`). But I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to load a module "as" a specific name, as in Python. That would allow me to `load "module-1.lisp" as mod` and then `load "module-2.lisp" as mod` in a loop.

Pseudocode:

```
for path in directory
    (load path as mod)
    (mod:function)
```

If there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do, feel free to say so! Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You're confusing modules with packages.

Comment: Ok, then how do I load _packages_?

Comment: You don't load packages. Packages are created by the files you load, and the file decides the package name. It's just a coincidence or convention that the package has the same name as the module.

Comment: The module contains something like `(defpackage "MOD" ...)` and there's no way to override the name.

Comment: Ohh ok. Is there a way to do what I need without resorting to `EVAL`?

Comment: It's not an automatically created name like Python modules. Modules aren't even part of the CL language.

Comment: After you load the code you could use [`PACKAGE-RENAME`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rn_pkg.htm)

Comment: But that could break things, since the code in the package might refer to it using the old name.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I'll test `PACKAGE-RENAME` and hope nothing breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick summary of packages and systems

*"Loading as"* is not something meaningful in Common Lisp, because loading is not the same as defining a new system or package. In Python, a file is a module etc. but not in Lisp.

Lisp has a concept of *packages*, which are namespaces. They are used to organize *symbols* (symbols are first-class values). In other words, they use, export or maybe shadow symbols from other packages and that's it. When you evaluate `(in-package pack)`, you can write all *accessible* symbols from `pack` directly, like `my-fun`, otherwise you need to fully qualify symbols, as `some-package:their-func`.
There are extensions that allows you to import a package with a different name, but this is not standard (see https://github.com/phoe/trivial-package-local-nicknames)

Loading a Lisp script is not necessarily the same as defining a package, it depends on what belongs in the file (if it as `defpackage` forms).

When you want to organize your source code in Lisp, you define a *system*, using [ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/index.html#SEC_Contents). A system list all its dependencies, its components (files) and the dependencies between their components. That's how you describe in which order files should be loaded, compiled, tested, etc.

Packages and systems are independant but in small systems you often have the the same name for a system and the unique package it defines. For larger systems there might be multiple packages.

See [21. Programming in the Large: Packages and Symbols](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html).

#### Your question

Each of your file needs to define a package, to avoid polluting a single namespace, for example:

```
(defpackage :common-name.01
   (:use :cl :utils)
   (:export #:run-me))

(in-package :common-name.01)

;; some code
```

But once they are all loaded, either using your approach or by defining a proper ASDF system, you want to be able to access all the `RUN-ME` functions, in all the packages.

You can write some introspective code that lists packages, etc. but I think a better approach would be to have a way for each of your file to *declare* that their `RUN-ME` functions should be registered in your framework, like test frameworks do.

For example, at the end of your files, you could write:

```
(provide-function 'run-me)
```

This assumes that e.g. your `utils` package defines and exports a function named `provide-function` that stores values in a central registry.

For example, in `utils.lisp`:

```
(defpackage :utils
   (:use :cl) 
   (:export #:provide-function
            #:run-all))

(in-package :utils)

(defvar *all-interesting-functions* nil)

(defun provide-function (f)
  (pushnew f *all-interesting-functions* :test #'eql))
```

And when you want to run all the functions, you can iterate over this list:

```
(defun run-all ()
  (mapcar #'funcall *all-interesting-functions*))
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you! This really lifted the fog around packages/modules/loading!

Comment: @OliverSandli Thanks